# How to show count in a Power BI matrix by combination of dimensions?

Tags: matrix, powerbi

I have a table like this

| Category | User | Date from | Date to |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Cat A | User 1 | 01-12-2022 | 01-12-2022 |
| Cat B | User 1 | 01-12-2022 | 01-12-2023 |
| Cat C | User 1 | 01-12-2022 |  |
| Cat A | User 2 | 01-06-2022 | 01-12-2022 |
| Cat B | User 2 | 01-12-2022 |  |
| Cat A | User 3 | 01-12-2022 |  |
| Cat C | User 3 | 07-08-2020 | 01-09-2022 |

How can I have a matrix like this in Power BI?

```
|                  |   2020   |   2021 |  2022  | < ---min of year(date from)
| ---------------- | -------- | ------ | -------|
| Cat A x Cat B    |   0      |   0    |    2   |  <-- count of Users who in Cat A AND Cat B
| Cat A x Cat C    |   1      |   0    |    1   |  <-- count of Users who in Cat A AND Cat C
| Cat B x Cat C    |   0      |   0    |    1   |  <-- count of Users who in Cat B AND Cat C
```

Thanks        |

I try put the 'Category' in both 'Column' and 'Row', but it doesn't work

Comment: First, having DateFrom, DateTo columns isn't proper dimensional modeling.  You need a separate fact row for each year.  And what do you mean by combining the categories?  Can you clarify?

Comment: I think he's getting at INTERSECT(setA, setB)